# how to play base64 wav file in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer, browser, html5-audio

I need to play base64 wav file in IE8. For other browsers I can use the HTML5  tag, but IE8 does not support it. There are lot of HTML5/Flash players, but the problem that Flash does not support WAV audio format :(. The other option is use the  tag to play wav on IE and it's work perfect if you set the file name as SRC parameter, but looks like does not support coded format. Could any body provide some idea how to resolve it? I do not have possibility to   change audio format or exclude coding.

Sample:

```
<embed autostart=true width=0 height=0 name="sound1" 
    src="data:audio/wav;base64,UklGRhwMAABXQVZFZm10IBAAAAABAAEAgD4AAIA+AAABAAgAZGF0Ya4LAACAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAf3hxeH+AfXZ1eHx6dnR5fYGFgoOKi42aloubq6GOjI2Op7yt......">
```

this solution does not work.

Comment: 3 years and still nothing, I wish there was a simple way of doing this...